# Homestead no input file specified for custom PHP project

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, homestead

I'm working with `Homestead`. `Laravel` apps are just serving fine, but when I try to setup some custom script, it shows me that `No input file specified.`

Here is my `yaml` file.

```
---
ip: "192.168.30.30"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/Mubin/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public

    - map: dev.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/dev/index.php
databases:
    - homestead
```

I just want to put all my code under dev folder and want to access it from `vagrant homestead box`

Guide where am I doing wrong?

PS.

I tried to remove index.php from the end, and then `nginx` throws `403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone having the same issue, I found a solution, mocked one may be; but it did work for me.

I added new `public` folder in my `dev folder` and place all my other custom `PHP` scripts put in that.

Directory structure was something like this for me

```
dev
    public
        folder1
            index.php
        folder2
            index.php
        folder3
            index.php
        ...
```

and I was able to access it like this

```
dev.local/folder1/index.php
dev.local/folder2/index.php
dev.local/folder3/index.php
```

and here is my `Homestead.yaml` file

```
---
ip: "192.168.30.30"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/Mubin/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public

    - map: dev.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/dev/public
databases:
    - homestead
```

and in my `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1    dev.local test.app
```

Hope this will help someone, someday. :)

I'd set up vagrant for `laravel` and custom `PHP` projects. Also, integrated with `PHP Storm` to work with `x-debug`. Leave a message if you've any issue.

Happy coding, x-debugging.